# What are some other examples of non-nucleophilic acids, other than boronic acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reactivity

Boronic acids can react as a Lewis acid, after reaction they are not good nucleophiles as the conjugate base. What are some other examples of such non-nucleophilic acids (or acids that have a non-nucleophilic conjugate base)?

Comment: Sulfuric acid: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/synthesis-of-nitrocellulose/2745#2745

Comment: Perchloric acid

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Non-coordinating_anions